# ¿Cómo llenar un dropdownlist con datos en sqlserver?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Que tal, estoy trabajando en c# y asp.net. Yo tengo un dropdownlist como el siguiente:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
```

Y una tabla en sql server de la cual me gustaría que tomara dichos valores.

¿Cómo puedo llenar el dropdownlist con datos en sqlserver?

Comment: Por favor, agregue mas información en la pregunta sobre qué ha intentando y/o muéstrenos cuál fragmento del código no está funcionando.

Answer (score 3):

Un ejemplo:

```
public void dropdownnumero()
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strcon);

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT numero FROM tabla where Estado ='Registrado'"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cn.Open();
                DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Numero";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma más adecuada es usar el soporte de enlace a datos que proporciona ASP.NET, es decir, a través de la propiedad `DataSource`

Puedes encontrar un ejemplo de uso en la [documentación del control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx) en MSDN

En el código HTML tendrías:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ColorList" runat="server">
```

En el código de servidor, en el evento de carga de la página tendrías esto:

```
  void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

     // Load data for the DropDownList control only once, when the 
     // page is first loaded.
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {

        // Specify the data source and field names for the Text 
        // and Value properties of the items (ListItem objects) 
        // in the DropDownList control.
        ColorList.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
        ColorList.DataTextField = "ColorTextField";
        ColorList.DataValueField = "ColorValueField";

        // Bind the data to the control.
        ColorList.DataBind();

        // Set the default selected item, if desired.
        ColorList.SelectedIndex = 0;

     }

  }
```

- Primero se establece en la propiedad DataSource el resultado devuelto por la consulta a la base de datos
- Después se configurar que campos de la base de datos se usan como valor seleccionado y el texto que se muestra al usuario (en este caso se usa el mismo para los dos)

La consulta a la base de datos se realizaría en el método `CreateDataSource` que sería similar esto:

```
ICollection CreateDataSource() 
{
    string selectQuery = @"select ...";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    return dv;
}
```

También hay otras formas "más modernas" de conseguir esto, por ejemplo usando el control [SqlDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w1kdt8w2(v=vs.100).aspx) o la nueva propiedad [`SelectMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.selectmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) que introdujeron en .NET 4.5 y lo que llaman [Enlace modelo y formularios Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/retrieving-data) ([aquí](http://www.codigomaestro.com/asp-net/modelo-de-enlace-de-datos-con-dropdownlist-en-asp-net-4-5-iqueryable/) tienes un artículo en español)

Answer (score 0):

Así es como lo manejo en algunos formularios, solamente invocas el método y te carga la información deseada.

```
public void CargarCbbxSim()
{
    //se inicializa un datatable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //se crea la coneccion a la b.dd
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MXSILWNCN11C04R;Initial Catalog=DPP;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Mexico2015"))
    {//se realiza la consulta
        string query = "select distinct NumSem from Semana order by NumSem desc ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        //se carga en la variable da
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    //segun se requiere se puede mostrar un valor y guardar otro y se carga al cbbx
    cbbxSimulacion.DisplayMember = "NumSem";
    cbbxSimulacion.ValueMember = "NumSem";
    cbbxSimulacion.DataSource = dt;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Disculpen, no se mucho español, pero puedes hacer asi:

```
private void PopulateUnits()
{
    public static readonly String SelectUnitsQuery = "Select distinct unit from masterunits"; 
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectUnitsQuery, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).DataSource = dt;
                ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).DisplayMember = "Unit";
                ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).ValueMember = "Unit";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui hay un checkboxlist llamado "checkedListBoxUnits" que lleno con la query "SelectUnitsQuery"

Comment: ty bro, but have you any idea how to make it with dropdownlist?

Comment: Tal vez este le puede aydar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227510/what-is-the-right-way-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-from-a-database

Comment: Hi @B.ClayShannon thank you for answer the question. I like you are learning Spanish, take a look here: www.duolingo.com and https://www.memrise.com/ for learning more! May the force be with you!

Comment: @fredyfx: Gracias; estoy en duolingo (mas que 600 dias corriendo), pero nunca he oido de memrise; Yo lo miro.

Comment: de nada! Con memrise estoy aprendiendo japonés. keep rocking!

Comment: Que raro; acababa a decidor o yo bebe Asahi o algo distinto esta noche al restaurante Korean.